# explain = \ operator in julia, gradient, short hand

Tags: julia

I have this line in Julia. A is a Nx2 matrix/array and series is a N-vector. What does this do

`gradient = \(A, series)`

is it the beta from regression of `series ~ A`

Comment: Note that `\ ` is a binary operator, so you would normally use it like this: `gradient = A \ series`.

Answer (score 3):

In the Julia REPL simply press `?` to go for help mode, than type the function name and press ENTER. Here is the beginning of help output for the `\` function.

```
help?> \
search: \

  \(x, y)

  Left division operator: multiplication of y by the inverse of x on the left. Gives floating-point results for integer arguments.
```